# Flutter image cropper and adjust brightness

Tags: flutter, image, dart, mobile, brightness

If there is any library available in flutter which have both crop and adjust brightness of image??

I have tried the **image_cropper** for crop the image and **fhoto_editor** for adjust brightness. But here I need these two functionalities in a single page. Any library available for that? Anyone have any idea??? Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend this package to build that functionality yourself: https://pub.dev/packages/image.
It is widely adopted as THE image processing package and it can do both:
For cropping use: [copyCrop](https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/copyCrop.html)
For brightness adjustments use: [adjustColor](https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/adjustColor.html)

You need to do the computation in another isolate to avoid blocking the ui thread.
Read about isolates [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/isolates-in-flutter-a0dd7a18b7f6)